# Diff of module version releases

Tags: 7, debugging

I'm trying to debug an error I'm encountering in the latest version of the Custom Formatters module and I'm encountering a common problem I have in debugging.  There's no easy way to do a project-wide diff of project from release to release.  I'd like to easily diff https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters 7.x-2.4 with 7.x-2.3.  I can use software locally to do that, but [github has spoiled me](https://github.com/blog/612-introducing-github-compare-view) I guess.  Am I missing a hidden function of drupal.org that shows diffs between releases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone down the project via

`git clone --branch 7.x-2.x http://git.drupal.org/project/custom_formatters.git`

When in the directory do a `git diff 7.x-2.4..7.x-2.3` and review the output.

If you don't want to scroll through your terminal, try `git diff 7.x-2.4..7.x-2.3 > version-change.diff` and pop the output into a diff viewer.

I wish cgit had this built it, but the diff viewer in it only supports per commit (as far as I know)

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't think it'd be quite that easy to do in Git.  I still think it'd be nice to see diffs on drupal.org/cgit.drupalcode.org, but this is a solid solution.  I found more `git diff` tips on tags on this other SO post for anyone else who's interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3211829/721065